# Calling C function JNI from Java Class

Tags: java, c, android-studio, compilation, java-native-interface

I created a JNI folder in my APP in Android Studio, I copied all my C files, but I need to call only one: `NeuralNetwork.c`, there are also `NeuralNetwork_initialize.c` and `NeuralNetwork_terminate.c`. I already have my CMakeFile.

I know I need to create another C file with something like this (it's called main.c):

```
#import <jni.h>
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_dsp_testapp_NewRecordingActivity_getString(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello World from C!");
}
```

But, I need it to call specifically my `NeuralNetwork.c`, I know also I have to use the initialize and terminate somehow, but don't really know how.

Now, in my Java class I did this:

```
System.loadLibrary("my_src");
```

my_src is the name of my library generated with my CMake file.
But I don't know how to call then my `main.c` function.

- `NeuralNetwork.c` gives me just a double: 1, or 0 and has 5 vector inputs with length of 256.

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to create a Java class with the qualified name (class + package) corresponding to what you used in your library (`com.dsp.testapp.NewRecordingActivity`). Then you need to declare the method as `native`:

`public native getString(Object obj)`

Afterwards, just create an object of this class and call the method.

Comment: Okay that's fine, but how do I specify in my c class I showed you the C function I need to call?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. If you want to call a `C` function from  inside `C` code, then just call the function (assuming that its header file in included).

Comment: If you're asking about "how does Java know which C function to call" - it decodes it from the C function name. Basically, it will call `Java_package_name_with_dots_replaced_by_underscores_methodName`.

Comment: Yes, I mean how does java know which C function to call, but it will call the one i put before, I mean that will return me a Hello World from C. I need it to call a function called NeuralNetwork.c that returns me a 0 or a 1

Comment: `NeuralNetwork.c` is not a function, it's a source file.

Comment: I told you what the pattern for resolving C functions from Java is. You just have to provide the proper C function with the proper signature and Java will automatically know how to call it.

Comment: Sorry I'm new, this is my first time. So how can I get the values of that source file? or how can I access it?

Comment: I don't know, you haven't provided the source for the `NeuralNetwork.c` file or even the signature of the C function you want to call.

Comment: that file is in my JNI folder. It's in CPP - src - NeuralNetwork.c

Comment: Well, it apparently contains some function that you want to call, but we don't know what the function is. C is not Matlab. A source file does not define a "script", it's just a container for functions. You want a specific function, you call a specific function.

Comment: It has a method like this: double NeuralNetwork(const double emg[256], const double eda[256], const double
                     ax[256], const double ay[256], const double az[256]) and it returns a double, I simply need to call this from Java, pass it the inputs it needs and for it to return me the double (0 or 1), that's it.

Comment: Okay, so now you have to somehow pass arrays from Java over to C-land. See eg. http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/doc/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/array.html for some guides on how to transfer array data via JNI.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed. Sorry, my question wasn't clear

Comment: Just last one method, how do I specify that's the method I want to pass arrays to?

Comment: You don't. You have to create a wrapper JNI function that calls it, something like: 

`JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_com_dsp_testapp_NewRecordingActivity_getNeuralNetwork(JNIEnv *env, jdoublearray param1, jdoublearray param2 <and so on>) {
return NeuralNetwork(transform(param1), transform(param1) <and so on>)
}`

Comment: For info on how to transform `jdoubleArray`s to native C arrays of `double`, see http://statweb.stanford.edu/~naras/java/course/lec5/lec5.html

Comment: Perfect, thank you. My last last question (I'm really sorry) is for my Java class, because it's from there I need to pass the parameters. I have this: public static void main(double[] arg1, double[arg2], ...) and that should be fine or how should I pass the inputs for them to get to the JNI wrapper?

Comment: You need to have a function that corresponds to the C method you made. So: 

`public native double getNeuralNetwork(double[] param1, double[] param2 <and so on>);`

Comment: And it has to be in the class that corresponds to the C method signature.